# Python: Split a python array into 3 parts where flagged

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have an array `a=[2,4,5,'Flag',3,7,'Flag',2,5]`.

Want to break this up into `b[0]=[2,4,5]`,`b[1]=[3,7]`,`b[2]=[2,5]`

How do I do this? Can use numpy.

Comment: Look at numpy.split

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a=[2,4,5,'Flag',3,7,'Flag',2,5]
>>> b = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, lambda x: x == 'Flag') if not k]
>>> b
[[2, 4, 5], [3, 7], [2, 5]]
```

Comment: Muchos gracias senor. I would have preferred not to use groupby, an extension I am not familiar with, but hey, good day to learn something new!

Answer (score 0):

With simple `for` loop:

```
a = [2, 4, 5, 'Flag', 3, 7, 'Flag', 2, 5]
result = [[]]
for i in a:
  if i == 'Flag':
    result.append([])
  else:
    result[-1].append(i)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[[2, 4, 5], [3, 7], [2, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank You, kind sir. Exactly what I was looking for!